# What is the accuracy of the Decimal data type?

Tags: excel, vba, floating-accuracy

I could not find anywhere which states VBA has a special variable for number e, so I figured a hefty number of decimal places would suffice.
The manual states as follows:

> You can use Decimal variables for money values. The advantage is the precision of the values. The Double data type is faster and requires less memory, but it is subject to rounding errors. The Decimal data type retains complete accuracy to 28 decimal places.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types

I've tried doing `Dim e@` ("@" being the decimal identifier from the manual), as well as this format

```
Dim MyDecimal As Variant
MyDecimal = CDec(3000000000000)
```

from https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/decimal-data-type.htm

However, when I try initializing `e` with the value `2.7182818284590452353602874713`, it gets rounded down to `2.71828182845905`. What's going on here? Can 28 decimal places not actually be utilized?

Comment: When checking docs online you need to be careful you're not looking at VB.NET, which is an entirely different platform from VBA except in a syntactical sense.

Comment: https://newtonexcelbach.com/2015/10/26/the-vba-decimal-data-type/ has some useful info on Decimal.  Might help your post to include a full example of what you did when testing, since getting numbers into and out of a Decimal type in Excel primarily means working with text (since cells with numeric formatting can't hold the same precision as a Decimal type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's going on here? Can 28 decimal places not actually be utilized?

This is because, when you do like that, the value is read as a *Double*, thus truncated to what this data type can hold, before `CDec` converts it.

```vb
? CDec(2.7182818284590452353602874713)
 2.71828182845904 

? CDec(CDbl("2.7182818284590452353602874713"))
 2.71828182845904 

? CDec("2.7182818284590452353602874713")
 2.7182818284590452353602874713
```